# Finding the derivatives given the figure.

Tags: calculus

I'm currently working on a calculus problem and find myself a bit stuck. I gone through my notes and textbooks, but i'm still having trouble grasping a particular concept. Can someone help me figure out this problem please.

With the given [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws1mH.png), for $h(x) = f(g(x))$ and $k(x)= g(f(x))$ .

I have to estimate the derivatives of these: $h'(1)$; $h'(2)$; $k'(1)$;  $k'(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

$h(x) = f(g(x))$ and $k(x)= g(f(x))$ .

To estimate the derivatives of : $h'(1)$; $h'(2)$; $k'(1)$; $k'(2)$,

Formula for derivatives :

- $h'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$
- $k'(x)= g'(f(x))f'(x)$ .

Now you can try.

Comment: yahh i have tried, but i dont know what f'(x) is at some point like x=1 or x=2 . Can u help me pls :((...

Comment: @TuấnNguyễnHữu: you do know that the derivative of a function is the tangens of the angle of the tangent line? From there, you should be able to find it.